# .removeClass() jQuery adds the removed class instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, removeclass

I'm having a issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/wkCV6/

When i click the `contacto` button it is ok and it opens properly. But when I click on `volver`, it removes the classes and  *immediately* adds it again. I noticed this, when I put some alerts between the execution. 
You can see it in my jsfiddle.

Here is the JS I'm using.

```
$(function () {
    $("div.arrastre").on("click", function () {
        $(this).find("div.bloque").addClass("rotated");
        var esto = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            esto.find("div.bloque div.back").addClass("agrandar");
            esto.addClass("agrandar")
        }, 100);
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("div#volver").on("click", function () {
        var esto = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            esto.closest("div.bloque").removeClass("rotated");
            if (esto.closest("div.back").hasClass("agrandar")) {
                esto.closest("div.back").removeClass("agrandar");
                alert("se supone que quité la clase agrandar en back ");
            };

            if (esto.closest("div.arrastre").hasClass("agrandar")) {
                esto.closest("div.arrastre").removeClass("agrandar");
                alert("se supone que quité la clase agrandar en arrastre");
            };
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click `div#volver`, the click event is dispatched and bubbles up to the document, triggering on every ancester.

You trigger the call back that you first set on `div.arrastre` because it's a parent of `#volver`.

`setTimeout` is called, causing the class to be added 100ms after the click on `#volver`.

To prevent a click event from bubbling, you can just `return false;` in the set callback or `stopPropagation` :

```
$("div#volver").on("click",function(event){
    // your code
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkCV6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** http://jsfiddle.net/2S34N/

Note: code acting funny because of the event aligned `:)` I have added new `settimeout` also jsut for a precaution sake `e.preventDefault()`.

hope htis fits the need `:)`

**Code**

```
//CAJAS DE CLICK 

$(function () {
    $("div.arrastre").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find("div.bloque").addClass("rotated");
        var esto = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            esto.find("div.bloque div.back").addClass("agrandar");
            esto.addClass("agrandar")
        }, 100);
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("div#volver").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var esto = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            esto.closest("div.bloque").removeClass("rotated");
            if (esto.closest("div.back").hasClass("agrandar")) {
                esto.closest("div.back").removeClass("agrandar");
                alert("se supone que quité la clase agrandar en back ");
            };

            if (esto.closest("div.arrastre").hasClass("agrandar")) {
                esto.closest("div.arrastre").removeClass("agrandar");
                alert("se supone que quité la clase agrandar en arrastre");
            };
        }, 200);
    });
});
```